# how to get double value from Firebase Remote Config in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

[image]

I have a default value in remote config console like the image above, I need to get that double value. in Android, I can get it like this

```
val remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
val value = remoteConfig.getDouble("parameter_name")
```

but now I am confused how to get that double value for iOS, it seems there is no `getDouble` equivalent in swift, so what should I do ?

```
let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
let value = // what should i write in here ?
```

Answer (score 2):

You could read it as a String form the config, and then parse the String into a Double.

```
if let valueAsString = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configValue(forKey: "yourKey").stringValue {
    if let valueAsDouble = Double(valueAsString) {
        // you have your value as a Double now
    } else {
        print("Not a valid number: \(valueAsString)")
    }
}
```

Firebase also offers "numberValue". The firebase code internally is:

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.stringValue.doubleValue]
```

This means: it returns 0 if the value cannot be converted. You have more control with the String way.